# Converting XML file to Java LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, xml, collections, jaxb

I have an XML file and I need to parse its content to `LinkedHashSet` which stores objects of my own class. For example, collection class:

```
public class person{ 
    private long id; 
    private String name; 
    private int age; 
}
```

And so XML would like be like that:

```
<root> 
    <person1> 
        <id>1</id> 
        <name>Bob</name> 
        <age>25</age> 
    </person1> 
    <person2> 
        <id>2</id> 
        <name>Alex</name> 
        <age>15</age> 
    </person2> 
</root>
```

and so on. 
I have found some stuff with JAXB, but there always are examples for only one object, not for the whole collection. So my question is how to convert XML to a `LinkedHashSet`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (FYI I changed the xml a little bit)

```
<employee>
<person>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <age>25</age>
</person>
<person>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Alex</name>
    <age>15</age>
</person>
</employee>
```

The class of person

```
public class Person {

private long id;
private String name;
private int age;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

The class of employee

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee {

  @XmlElement(name = "person")
  private LinkedHashSet<Person> listOfPerson;

  public LinkedHashSet<Person> getListOfPerson() {
    return listOfPerson;
  }
}
```

And finally we can get this data (getEmployee().getListOfPerson() do with that what you want to do )) )

```
public Employee getEmployee() throws JAXBException {
    File file = new File("data.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    Employee employee = (Employee) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

    return employee;
}
```